# Add a UIView above the UINavigationBar in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I need help for adding a View above my actual navigation bar, an example of what I am looking for it can be Google + app when you open the side bar menu 
[image]

Comment: Go ahead, there's no issue that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation controller needs to be contained by another view controller. Inside this view controller you can setup a gesture recognizer that (for example) detects swiping gestures. Whenever such a gesture is detected you can than tell the view controller that contains your navigation controller to bring in the menu.